# Display time spent on an issue per timeframe in jira

Tags: jira

I wanna display the time spent per issue in a specific timeframe. Creating a rich filter that shows time spent is very straight forward, however, selecting the right timeframe is tricky.

Possibility #1:

```
resolved > -12w
```

That selects issues resolved within the last quarter, but then all time is displayed, even when the issue is is much older and a lot of time has been booked more than 12 weeks ago.

Possibility #2:

```
created > -12w
```

That selects issues created within the last quarter, and automatically excludes issues that are still being worked on but are older

Possibility #3

```
created > -12w and resolved < -4w
```

That selects issues created and resolved and disregards issues going between timeframe boundaries.

Possibility #4

```
worklogdate > -12w and worklogdate < -4w
```

That would select only issues with correct worklog dates, i.e., issues that REALLY have been worked on in that timeframe, but when I then analyze worklogtime or time spent, that is still all the time worked on the issue, not just the time within the specified timeframe.

Any idea how I could achieve showing the time spent per issue of a very specific timeframe?